# HttpClient Working In .NET Core But Not Framework 4.7.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

I'm currently trying to send a [GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) request to a site called [Monday](https://monday.com/)

With [.NET CORE](https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/dotnet/hello-world-tutorial) the below code works and returns the [Json](https://www.json.org/) content as expected, however when I use the same code with [Framework 4.7.2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/04/30/announcing-the-net-framework-4-7-2/) I get this error 
`ProtocolViolationException: Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type.`
My question is, why would this be working in .NET Core and not Framework 4.7.2 on a standard Console Application.

```
    static void GetFoo()
    {
        Task task = Task.Run(async() =>
        {
            string url = "https://api.monday.com:443/v1/boards/foo/pulses.json?api_key=bar";
            using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
            using (HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url))
            {
                httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("Cach-Control",": max-age=0, private, must-revalidate");
                httpRequestMessage.Content = new StringContent("", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                HttpResponseMessage result = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
                string data = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                // Just want to see a result for now, so writing it to the console.
                Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data).ToString());
            }
        });
        Task.WaitAll(task);
    }
```

Comment: what happens if you comment out the last `Console.WriteLine`?

Comment: @JohnB same error

Comment: how about using `HttpWebRequest` instead?

Comment: There is a discussion about this on [github corefx](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/28135)